# "Serial potential drop" or "series of potential drops"

Tags: word-usage

I would like to use the word *serial* in the sense that it denotes a sequential arrangement of objects. In that regard, is it better to say "serial potential drop" instead of "a series of potential drops"?

Comment: Why in the world would you want to do that? You already have _potential_ denoting that the drop is a drop of potential (one assumes EMF without context), and now you want to add another complex adjective on the same side, denoting that there is a series of such drops. Every time you compress something like this, you make it harder to read and more likely to be misunderstood. That's why we allow modifiers on both sides of the noun -- so they can spread out the meaning and clarity. _A series of drops in potential_ may be dull, but it's certainly clear.

Comment: What @John said. The only justification I can see for the "shorter, but more opaque" version would be if you're writing in a context where you *repeatedly* need to contrast and compare two systems where the primary difference is that one involves dropping the potential all the way down in a single component, where the other does this using a series of drops. In which case you might reasonably place the first use in "scare quotes" and just use it casually thereafter, having already alerted the reader that he needed to make an effort with the first one to save time later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are speaking of a set of voltage drops across resistors arranged in series, use the latter phrasing: “a series of potential drops” or perhaps better,  “a series of voltage drops”.   “Serial potential drop” probably is technically ok, ie is not wrong, but because of being rarely used may jar the reader.   However, if you want to emphasize that there is a descending scale of voltages along a resistor chain, as found for example in 256-resistor or 1024-resistor flash ADC parts, serial potential drop might be an appropriate phrase to use.

Answer (score 1):

> This series of potential drops...

Talking about the series.

> These serial potential drops...

Talking about the individual drops, and noting (or reiterating) that they are part of a series.

As such, they're not quite the same, and one could very well make use of both.

The latter is awkward though. It would be fine if you'd already introduced the series, so the reader's mind has that series as a fresh concept in mind and so won't have to do too much mental work to piece the phrase together.

It would not be so good to introduce the concept as "serial potential drops", unless rewording to use the former was itself awkward.